# Simulate missed call from ADB shell

Tags: adb, shell, missed-calls

On the ADB shell, I run the command

```
adb -s <serial_number> shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:123456
```

to place a call on my testing device. It works great. But I also want to simulate a missed call from the ADB shell, as I would by telnet with the command `gsm cancel +123456`, for example.

I cannot find anywhere how to do this. Is this even possible with ADB? If so, how?

P.S: the command `adb -s <serial_number> shell input keyevent 6` is not an answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a rooted device or eng build device, you can push TeleCommTests.apk under `data/apps/TelecommTests/` which has to be built along with Android source code and then fire the below intent from ADB:

```
adb shell am start -a android.telecom.testapps.ACTION_START_INCOMING_CALL -d "tel:123456789"
```